# Выбрать все даты из базы данных mySQL?

Tags: дата, php, mysql

Всем привет. Есть база данных есть поле date типом данных timestamp.

Так вот делаю запрос

```
SELECT * FROM history_sale hs WHERE DATE(hs.date) BETWEEN '2014-06-03' AND '2014-06-05';
```

Выборка работает отлично. Но нужно сделать так

```
SELECT * FROM history_sale hs WHERE DATE(hs.date) BETWEEN '2014-06-03' AND 'текущая дата';
```

Как правильно написать запрос?

И второй вопрос. Я получаю из поле input дату в формате 03.06.2014
Так вот как передати эту даты в запрос, у меня структуры даты такая 2014-06-03, а из input получаю дату в формате 03.06.2014.

Как преобразовать эту дату?

Всем спасибо и спокойно ночи!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция [NOW()](http://sql.sh/fonctions/now) возвращает текущую дату и время. Функция [DATE()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-date-functions.htm#function_date) делает из даты и времени просто дату. Соответственно `DATE(NOW())` это текущая дата (хотя наверное хватит просто `NOW()`).

P.S. оказывается ещё есть [CURDATE()](http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/date-and-time-functions.html). В общем [гугель рулит](https://www.google.ru/search?q=mysql+текущая+дата).

Comment: Спасибо на первую часть вопроса ответили, как на счет второй?

Comment: Как-то так:

google://php перевод даты в другой формат

Лень самому гуглить.

Можно и на стороне SQL, там вроде есть какая-то функция вроде dataformat. Или в похапэ вручную, нарезать строку в массив по символу `.` а потом склеить элементы массива в другом порядке с разделителем `-`. Гугли про `php строка в массив` и `php массив в строку`.